# Social Comment Plugin for Facebook: user wall post is not image of page

Tags: facebook, xfbml, x-facebook-platform

My website has a facebook social plugin for comments. When a user posts a comment they have an option to post to their own wall. The image that goes with that wall post is not the image from the website which the comment plugin is on. Where is that image being pulled from?

Below is the html within the app page.

```
<meta property="og:type" content="website"/>
<meta property="og:image" content="http://mysite.com/images/image.png"/>
<meta property="og:title" content="My Site"/>
<meta property="og:url" content="http://mysite.html"/>
<meta property="og:site_name" content="My site"/>
<meta property="og:fb_id" content="1111111111"/>

<link rel="image_src" href="images/fb-thumb.png" />
<link rel="image_src" href="images/fb-thumb2.png" />

<iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/comments.php?app_id=1111111111&amp;href=http://mysite.com&permalink=1" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; width:800px" colorscheme="light" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

> The image that goes with that wall post is not the image from the website which the comment plugin is on.

If the linter target is different than the page the comment box is installed on, it is using the og:image as defined on that target page.

If you don't have markup access to the linter target page, create a redirect page containing the meta info you need (title, image, description, etc), with the redirect pointing to the eventual place you want users directed to if they click the link on their friends wall.